# MongDB level write count

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I need to figure out how many writes MongoDB has performed in the last hour against reads.

Is there an easy way to find these stats, which are needed to create an alarm. If the solution is command driven or Java based, it will be really helpful.

Comment: what kind of problem are you going to solve?

Comment: Take a look at this, some commands to return DB stats: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/monitoring/

Comment: Is this more of a database administration problem than a programming problem? You might find the answer you want in http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: i am trying to write a JMX Mbean , if any JMX bean given by mongo itself it is more than welcome. this will be used for monitoring purpose .

Comment: do you know about mongostats?

Answer (score 0):

after digging up source code of MongoDB jdbc driver . i finally able to get what is required . below is a code for it

```
    public class MongoJmxStat {

    private MongoClient mongo;

    public MongoJmxStat(MongoClient mongo) {
        this.mongo = mongo;
    }

    public CommandResult getServerStatus() {
        CommandResult result = getDb("mongoDB").command("serverStatus");
        if (!result.ok()) {

            throw new MongoException("could not query for server status.  Command Result = " + result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public DB getDb(String databaseName) {
        return MongoDbUtils.getDB(mongo, databaseName);
    }

    private int getOpCounter(String key) {
        DBObject opCounters = (DBObject) getServerStatus().get("opcounters");
        return (Integer) opCounters.get(key);
    }

    @ManagedMetric(metricType = MetricType.COUNTER, displayName = "Write operation count")
    public int getWriteCount() {
        return getOpCounter("insert") + getOpCounter("update") + getOpCounter("delete");
    }

    @ManagedMetric(metricType = MetricType.COUNTER, displayName = "Read operation count")
    public int getReadCount() {
        return getOpCounter("query") + getOpCounter("getmore");
    }

}
```